# iOS/Swift avoid duplicated symbols when embedding third-party library dependency into another library

Tags: ios, swift, linker, xcframework, duplicate-symbol

I'm interested in providing a library as an [XCFramework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/creating-a-multi-platform-binary-framework-bundle) to other developers, so that they can drag&drop it or use a Swift Package Manager to install and use that library.

Inside, however, that [XCFramework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/creating-a-multi-platform-binary-framework-bundle) uses multiple popular third-party dependencies.
I'd like it to be self-contained, i.e. so that using my library won't require the developer to install or link other third-party libraries or impose any restrictions on what library versions they could use. Because of this, I'm including all of the dependencies into the resulting XCFramework.

**Question**

What is the best way to avoid conflicts in this scenario? Considering [SwiftyBeaver](https://github.com/SwiftyBeaver/SwiftyBeaver) and [Apollo GraphQL iOS](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-ios) as the dependencies, what is the minimum that I have to rename?

- Should I rename just the targets that I'll be importing?
- Should I also rename the classes inside those libraries (as is the case with Objective-C)?
- Will including third-party libraries cause any conflicts / linker errors in Swift at all (if the app developer imports my framework alongside with those 3rd party libraries)?

Comment: I've corrected my question. I'm planning to put static libraries (`.a` ) and link them with the resulting framework.

Comment: Could you please be more concrete in your answer.

Comment: "The idea is not hiding from a developer what is included in a package." -> this is out of the question and I'd like not to expose the internals.

I've definitely seen SDKs with vendored libraries inside and that has actually caused conflicts for me, so that the SDK developer had to rename the classes, but that was in ObjC. This question is about avoiding the same issue but with Swift.

Comment: I've corrected my question. I think it was either a framework or a static library. The inclusion method is not very relevant to the question. We could replace the "framework" or "library" here with "target".

Comment: I didn't try it with latest Xcode, but in ~Xcode 13 having XCFramework with embedded 3rd-party libs was a nightmare. Conflicts is one of the issues, but also depends on how they integrate (cocoapods, packages, embedding), and supporting each of the options is very hard. So my recommendation would be: do not embed them. Make them a dependency for your xcframework instead. I.e. if someone use cocoapods, and your podspec lists all dependencies - that's all that is needed. For manual drag&drop you could also provide a "fat bundle", which includes all libs